# Can both model parameters in linear regression be called regression coefficients?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression

I was going through a review and I found that in the equation

$$
f(x_{i}) = w_{0} + w_{1}x_{i}  
$$

both $w_{1}$ and $w_{0}$ are being called **regression coefficients**.

I have found references on the internet and I see that there are examples supporting the same and against it in text such as:

**Against**

- Link [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegressionCoefficient.html)

"The slope b of a line obtained using linear least squares fitting is called the regression coefficient."

- Link [here](https://statisticsbyjim.com/glossary/regression-coefficient/)

" In linear regression, coefficients are the values that multiply the predictor values. Suppose you have the following regression equation: $y = 3X + 5$ In this equation, +3 is the coefficient, X is the predictor, and +5 is the constant."

**References that call them regression coefficients**

- Link of a paper [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/earth-and-planetary-sciences/regression-coefficient&sa=D&source=editors&ust=1621770652260000&usg=AOvVaw1D49o5fFi_lw0UAcQ9mUwy)

> The regression coefficients ($a$ and $b$) are estimated by minimizing the sum of squares of deviations of $y_i$ from the regression line. For a point $x_i$, the corresponding  given by the regression equation will be: $$y_{i} = a + bx_{i}$$

As per my understanding it should be that $a$ is constant and $b$ is the coefficient here. Can someone please shed some light on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid and used.

Yes, $a$ or $w_0$ are often called constant. However, one would also count constants among the coefficients.

The constant can be viewed as the "slope" of the constant predictor $x_0=1$, so that $w_0x_0=w_0$. In this case, even the constant would be "a value that multiplies the predictor values".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the assumption with $x_{0}=1$ makes a lot of sense, but should we not express that we have this value in our data, just to give mathematical validation to the same

Comment: I suppose you could. And if you use the matrix inversion steps to calculate the OLS coefficients yourself based on data, you might just include that 1-column in your X matrix. But when using standard software, nobody bothers to include that in the data.

Comment: Thanks makes a lot of sense